# how to make form input in middle

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

hello i use bootstrap 3 v3.36 have a project that have a navbar fixed top and slider and form search.
in slider area i want to put from search and 3 button like 2 dropdown and search button with display inline.

heres my code

```
<header>
      <!-- NAVBAR-START -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
          <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">brand</a>
          </div>

          <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">people <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="#">gallery</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">inspiration</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="#">Jobs oportunity</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">hirring a chief?</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">login|signup</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
      </nav>
      <!-- NAVBAR-END -->

      <!-- SLIDER-START -->
        <div id="slider">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        </div>
      <!-- SLIDER=END -->
      <!-- search-controller -->
        <div class="position-relative">
          <div class="search-controller">
            <form role="search">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
              </div>
              <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                  Dropdown1
                  <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                  Dropdown2
                  <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- search-controller END-->

    </header>
```

css

```
#slider img{
    width: 100%;

}


.search-controller .form-control{
    width: 60%;
    margin: auto;


}
.search-controller{
    position: absolute;
    top: auto;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 2000;
}
.position-relative{
    position: relative;
}
```

but with my code the input search and the other button cant get aline even i use `display:inline-block` how to do this?and how to make it responsive even i minimize for mobile because when i minimize my button collapse suddenly cant colapse?

or you can check the result here
http://codepen.io/vicario/pen/graqPm

thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by:" i want to put from search and 3 button like 2 dropdown and search button"..Please specify your requirements more clearly

Comment: i mean input type search with 2 buttons dropdown and button submit sir and it will get display inline-block.my bad sir

Comment: If you specify your problem clearly you would get better help. Remember users here have no idea about your code.

Comment: okay ill edit my description

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns
Try this maybe..

also for responsive design I suggest you read the getting started section and the following section:http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities
It will help you design your markup in the long run because by default bootstrap is responsive in nature ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? I put the form elements into a `.container` div, changed `.dropdown` and `.search-controller .form-control` to `display:inline-block` and removed the relative positioning from `.search-controller .form-control`. Also I added the `form-inline` class to the form:

```css
#slider img {
    width: 100%;
    /*height: 50%;*/
}

.search-controller .form-control {
    width: 60%;
    display:inline-block;
}

.dropdown{
 display:inline-block;
}

.search-controller {
    position: absolute;
    top: auto;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 2000;
}



.position-relative {
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
    <!-- NAVBAR-START -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">brand</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">people <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">gallery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">inspiration</a></li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Jobs oportunity</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">hirring a chief?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">login|signup</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
    <!-- NAVBAR-END -->

    <!-- SLIDER-START -->
    <div id="slider">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </div>
    <!-- SLIDER=END -->
    <!-- search-controller -->
 <div class="container">
 

    <div class="position-relative">
        <div class="search-controller">
            <form role="search" class="inline-form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
     <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
       Dropdown1
       <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
       <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
       <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
       <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
       Dropdown2
       <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
       <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
       <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
       <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- search-controller END-->
 </div>
 </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       #slider img{
       width: 100%;

    }


    .search-controller .form-control{
      width: 60%;
      margin: auto;


    }
    .search-controller{
      position: absolute;
       top: auto;
      bottom: 15px;
       left: 0;
       right: 0;
       z-index: 2000;
    }
    .position-relative{
       position: relative;
    }

<!-- language: lang-html -->

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<header>
      <!-- NAVBAR-START -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
          <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">brand</a>
          </div>

          <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">people <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="#">gallery</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">inspiration</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="#">Jobs oportunity</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">hirring a chief?</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">login|signup</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
      </nav>
      <!-- NAVBAR-END -->

      <!-- SLIDER-START -->
        <div id="slider">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        </div>
      <!-- SLIDER=END -->
      <!-- search-controller -->
        <div class="position-relative">
          <div class="search-controller">
            <form role="search">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
              </div>
              <div class="dropdown row"><div class="col-lg-4"></div><div class="col-lg-4">
                <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                  Dropdown1
                  <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
                </div><div class="col-lg-4"></div></div>
              <div class="dropdown row"><div class="col-lg-4"></div><div class="col-lg-4">
                <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                  Dropdown2
                  <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                </ul></div><div class="col-lg-4"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="row"><div class="col-lg-4"></div><div class="col-lg-4">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">Submit</button></div> <div class="col-lg-4"></div></div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- search-controller END-->

    </header>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: from my example above I hope you get an idea about using row col containers etc. plz read more bout them..good luck